# Firebug and jQuery selectors in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, firebug

I'm working on a web application and using the jQuery plug-in Colorbox to pop up a window that presents a form for editing elements of the parent window. I'm using Firebug to debug my Javascript and jQuery, and I noticed that I can't select an element in my Colorbox HTML form using the jQuery console command line. For instance:

$date = $("#date");

returns nothing when run from the jQuery console command line, even though I have an input element with id="date" and the Firebug "element inspect" pointer can find the element in the iFrame. Is there a way to get Firebug's console to access the elements in an iFrame?

Thanks for your help!
Doug

Comment: can you clarify, does the script work normally when part of the page, but not when run through the console?

Comment: did you try `var date = $("#date");`

Comment: The Javascript works in the Colorbox, it's just that I can't manipulate elements that are in the iFrame with jQuery in the Firebug console.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass iframe's document as a context for your selector, because iframe has its own separated DOM tree:

```
$('#date', $('iframe').get(0).contentDocument);
```

In order to get access in iframe's content, it must be loaded from same domain as parent document.

---

Just to elaborate here, `.contentDocument` property works in Chrome (and FF) but not in IE<8. You have to use `.document`.

Comment: Yaggo,
Thanks for your reply, can you elaborate a little more? I'm not "getting" what you mean by accessing the iFrame's context.
Thanks,
Doug

Comment: just to elaborate here, `.contentDocument` property works in Chrome (and FF) but not in IE. You have to use `.document`.

Answer (score 21):

You're looking for the `cd` method, documented here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API

Here's a bookmarklet I use to automate jumping into the iframe for any iframed Facebook application.  It should provide enough of an example to modify for your use.

```
javascript:with(_FirebugCommandLine){cd($$(".canvas_iframe_util")[0].contentWindow)}
```

Note that `with` is generally bad practice, but this is literally how Firebug executes what you type into the console, so I mimicked that.

After you've run this, everything you type into the command line executes in the context of the iframe.

Comment: This is genius.  Thank you for sharing that snippet.  It makes Facebook iframe app development much easier.

Comment: To clarify, if you're in the Firebug console all you need is the cd(iframedom.contentWindow)

Comment: In case it's helpful: I'm finding that I need .window instead of .contentWindow -- for some frames, not all. Thankfully, iframes are rare enough that I can't find very many to test.

Comment: Made this question a favorite, because bcherry and James Baker. (And I add this comment only to remind me of looking directly at James Bakers solution, the next time I need it.)