# firebug: how to cd to an iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, firebug

I have a facebook canvas application that runs in an iframe.  I would like to debug my page in firebug but can not get the javascript to scope to the iframe that is running my app.

the iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="[app_url_removed]" name="iframe_canvas" id="iframe_canvas" class="canvas_iframe_util" style="height: 905px;"></iframe>
```

i've tried all the following and none of them work:

```
cd(iframe_canvas)
cd(window.iframe_canvas)
cd(iframe_canvas.window)
cd($('iframe_canvas'))
```

I have firefox 3.6.13
and I have tried firebug 1.7a11 and firebug 1.6.2

also tried the bookmarklet and various other things from this link [Firebug and jQuery selectors in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495313/firebug-and-jquery-selectors-in-an-iframe) to no avail.

Comment: I am pretty sure if you look in the Firebug view, there is a "+" next to the iframe tag. If you expand that you can see what is loaded into the iframe. I can also see all the javascript calls from the iFrame code on the console.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, Im trying to call the javascript functions inside that iframe in the console. for instance I am using jquery in my iframe and I'd like to use the jquery selector to access a div and bind an event listener in the console to test.

Comment: I am doubtful if it's possible. You may need to open the iFrame in a separate window (by right clicking on it, and selecting open iFrame in a new Window). But if there is a way to debug JS in iFRame.. I would really like to know.

Comment: You can also read this Firebug tip:
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/planet-mozilla/firebug-tip-using-command-line-within-an-iframe/ Honza

Answer (score 105, accepted):

use one of these commands:

```
 cd(frames[0]) 
 cd(frames["iframe_canvas"])
```

and

```
 cd(top)
```

to return to the main window.

Still, due to a bug this currently doesn't work on cross-domain-iframes (http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3893). There are two test cases where you can test your evironment for both cases:

- https://getfirebug.com/tests/content/commandLine/cd.html
  (same domain, works for me: FF 3.6.13, FB 1.6.2)
- http://getfirebug.com/tests/issues/3893/issue3893.html
  (cross domain, fails)

Another possible source of surprise: if you execute more commands at once the cd command seems to not have an effect for the directly following commands:

```
 >>> cd(frames[0]); location.href;
 ["Current window:", Window cdFrame.html]
 "https://getfirebug.com/tests/content/commandLine/cd.html"
 >>> location.href
 "https://getfirebug.com/tests/content/commandLine/cdFrame.html"
```

Comment: thank you.  i used to be able to cd to the frame and now I can't i thought i forgot the syntax but this actually explains it as in facebook canvas apps using an iframe, the iframe is indeed cross domain.  I will follow the issue and get an update when it is fixed.

Comment: installed firefox 4 beta and 1.7 firebug and it is working now. thanks!

Comment: how would you cd into a frame inside a frame that have the same name attributes?

Answer (score 14):

In Chrome there is a dropdown at the <strike>bottom</strike> top* of the javascript console that lets you switch to a different frame to execute javascript in.  Works cross-domain too!

<sub>*Updated 2/10/14: In more recent versions of Chrome, this dropdown has been moved from the bottom to the top of the console.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Elements can be accessed as follows: `window.frames[x].document.getElementById("elementID");` where `x` would be the frame index and `elementID` is the element you are pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the wiki was not updated back when this question was asked, but now it has nice examples:
https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Cd

Basically, what you were missing to get the window from the iframe element was ".contentWindow"