# Change the context of the Safari 6 console to an iframe on the page

Tags: javascript, safari, console, web-inspector

I know that [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961229/is-there-a-way-to-change-context-to-iframe-in-javascript-console) let's you pick the context for the console's execution with a dropdown menu and that Firebug let's you `cd()` into an iframe. I can't figure out how to change the context in Safari's console. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Safari, unlike chrome and firefox, has no real support for this functionality and the only option seems to be to access the window object from the console. As you correctly point this will trigger cross domain policy issues, however provided you're running on mac (this does not work for some reason on windows) you can use

```
open -a '/Applications/Safari.app' --args --disable-web-security
```

to bypass this. And next on your jsbin you could use something along the lines of

```
window.frames[0]
```

to access the window of the page. As far as I can see there is no similar solution for windows, as

```
Safari.exe --disable-web-security
```

apparantly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The Iframe element itself is of Type Window within Console

```
<iframe id="frame" src="about:blank"/>
```

In Safari console then you simply work with

```
frame.document.write('bla');
```

please notice that 'frame' is shorthand for `document.getElementById('frame')`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work with iframes with a different domain than the host page. That's why the firebug `cd` command and the Chrome drop down menu for changing "contexts" are so useful...

Comment: Sure? I tried this with a different URL and it worked. Only for posting I changed this to about:blank.

Comment: Yup: http://jsbin.com/ojiley/2 -- when I open the Safari console and type: `document.getElementById("test-iframe").document` I get `undefined`: http://cl.ly/image/0N0v1l223w1m

Comment: try `document.getElementById("test-iframe").contentDocument` or `document.getElementById("test-iframe").contentWindow`. additionally you can print all parts of the frame to the console: `for(var key in document.getElementById("test-iframe")) console.log(key);`in order to find all useful attributes.

Comment: Nope, I still cannot access anything within the iframe. Are you sure you're using Safari 6.x?

Comment: Yes of course. Safari 6 on OS X Mountain Lion. And i tried them and i had access to the document object of the iframe.

Comment: Hmm @mr.VVoo can you tell me what code you've type into the Safari Web Inspector console to be able to access a dom element on the Amazon.com page in the iframe?

Comment: here's the screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/bildschirmfoto20130221u.png/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24935/discussion-between-aaron-gibralter-and-mr-vvoo)