# JavaScript Console: Can't select an element by its XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath, chromium

In any YouTube video page ([Gangnam Style](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0) for example), some elements can't be accessed by their XPath. From example, I'm trying to access the "Show more" button

[image]

by getting its XPath from the Inspect Window

[image]

and using this code

```
btn=$x('//*[@id="widget_bounds"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[7]/div[3]/span[1]');
```

but I get nothing, or more precisely, an empty list:

[image]

I've never encountered this problem before, are they using some sort of obfuscation trickery to prevent the item from being accessed?

Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: are sure there's not a frame in there somewhere? google loves them...

Comment: No idea, I'm a C++ programmer just dabbling in JavaScript, I'm not even sure what you mean :)

Comment: Did you try it in pieces and see where it breaks?

Comment: i mean you can't reach it from the top frame using xpath, you need to start at the nearest contentWindow, if the domain controls allow it. I just checked, and that is indeed your problem.

Comment: Is it on purpose? For obfuscation I mean? Another thing I tried was getting a list of all elements using `getElementsByTagName('*')`, and search through them, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Has nothing to do with obfuscation, it has to do with the fact it is not in the same window context.

Comment: @dandavis Aha, I think I understood the problem, there indeed is an iframe, and above it XPath works, but the XPath for anything inside its subtree doesn't. So how do I access elements inside the subtree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change context to iframe in javascript console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961229/is-there-a-way-to-change-context-to-iframe-in-javascript-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you want to reach is in an iframe on the page. BUT the problem is you will not be able to get to the content because the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is going to prevent it.

```
document.getElementById("I0_1392927253257").contentWindow.document

SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Check out [@sashoalm's link below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918214/javascript-console-cant-select-an-element-by-its-xpath/21918613?noredirect=1#comment33198727_21918613) to change the context of iframe in Chrome.

Comment: Wait, does that mean that anything inside an iframe is inaccessible from the JavaScript console?

Comment: Well the console is able to access it, but you are not going to be able to run JavaScript code on that frame. You would need to fetch the source of the iframe and open that up in a new window and run the code there.

Comment: Actually, turns out there is a question about that - [Is there a way to change context to iframe in javascript console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961229/is-there-a-way-to-change-context-to-iframe-in-javascript-console)