# How to access event "onplay()" for iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

I have two iframes in one page.

```
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="video1" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to access `onplay()` event of iframe, then i can able to stop second video(`#Video1`) while playing first one(`#Video`) and Stop first video(`#Video`) when playing Second(`#Video1`).

It is possible using `YoutubeAPI` but i do not want to use that because i have other url videos not Youtube videos(here i put youtube links instead orignal links to avoid copyright). Is there another way except `YoutubeAPI`. `YoutubeAPI` is not working on another link resources. Please Suggest.

Comment: You can't access the content of a cross-domain iframe in JS code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way to stop other videos while playing current one.

Answer (score 0):

It has two `<iframe>`. First, you need switch between `iframe`.

[Is there a way to change context to iframe in javascript console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961229/is-there-a-way-to-change-context-to-iframe-in-javascript-console)

After, here my code how to access to event onPlay() of `<iframe>`

```html
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<div class="module module-home-video">
    <span class="module-strip">Latest Product Video</span>
    <div id="video"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var player, playing = false;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'xmhtV4270NU',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(!playing){
            alert('onPlay is clicked');
            playing = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but as i mentioned i am restricted to use YoutubeAPI. Is there another way without using YoutubeAPI.